# TOC is not printed

Tags: table-of-contents

I have taken a template online but the TOC is not printed. I've googled but cant find an example similar to mine. The template is very large so I only copied in the code I believe is relevant, but I'm a beginner in this so there might other places in the code that causes this.

```
\documentclass[ikp_flumes, 10pt, english, crop, info, print]{tthesis}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\lstset{language=C, breaklines=true}

\usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor=black, citecolor=black,%
            urlcolor=black, hyperindex, bookmarks,%
            plainpages=false, naturalnames=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{}
\makeFrontMatter
\listoffigures
\clearpage

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Method}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use template larger than you can handle. You will spent to much time to debug them. The size of the template should be in relation to your latex skills.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Currently, your code is not compilable.  At the very least, an `\end{document}` is missing.  Is your document class really `tthesis`?  Also, your code doesn't seem to be minimal, but includes a lot of additional packages.  Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.  When you make your code smaller, this might give you a hint of where the problem lies.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Where did you get the template from? Maybe you could post a link to that template? Otherwise it's very difficult to help you. It would be especially helpful, if you could provide the `tthesis.cls` file, because one can only compile your MWE, if one has it.

Comment: Why the `{}` after `\tablofcontents`? Shouldn't `tableofcontents` and `listoffigures` be on adjacent lines instead of separated by `\makeFrontMatter`?

Comment: Hi all, you're all right with the comments. I have now started a blank project maybe (hopefully) it will be more use of my time (I've just started on my master thesis). I have noticed that example online use \include{myfilename} and have myfilename.txt saved in same folder as the main.txt. Now I'm trying to do the same but (again) it doesn't print anything.

Comment: I'll close this question and start a new one.

Comment: You can edit the question ;-)

Comment: For a good start, there are two very good *free* ebooks, [LaTeX for complete novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html) and [Using LaTeX to wrie a PhD](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/index.html). Do a bit of reading and in two days you will be ready to get going. With a template, you *will* loose time debugging it.